Accurately batch trim first few seconds of video file with ffmpeg
I have a large number of .mp4 files and I want to trim just the first 3 seconds off of each.
I tried using the following command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:03 -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
That cut the audio well but it looked like it removed some extra video and left it blank for a bit then stretched the first few frames to compensate. It looked horrible.
I found this post and I think the "Slow but Accurate" route is the one I want but I'm not familiar enough with everything after "-filter_complex" to be able to adapt it to my more simple use case.
Can someone show me how to adapt that command to my use case or tell me a better way that I can accurately cut the video files without having to bring each one into kdenlive or something like that?

The "Slow but Accurate" will reencode all files, which means time and heat, and also some drop it quality. Now, your trim start is "0" and the end is "03".

Time and heat are no issue. I don't care how long it takes. I just need an end product that looks good.

When you copy the video stream, it will cut on key frames. In order to have the cut on the exact location, at least that portion in between keyframes will need to be reencoded.
For a more simple approach, it suffices to leave out the -vcodec copypart to have ffmpeg encode to mp4 video with default quality settings. If the result does not look good, or if the conversion results in a too large file, then you will need to specify flags (these are specific to the format you encode to, so consult the manual) to control the quality, and experiment with these until video quality and file size are to your satisfaction.
It would be better, however, if you could just reencode the first part after 3 seconds up to the next key frame. To automate, however, some more complicated scripting would be needed. This Stackoverflow anwer hints on how one can reencode part of the file up to a key frame, then use the concat demuxer to join that reencoded part with the part remaining after the selected key frame. The difficulty here is that these keyframes will be different for each video, so a script would need to determine the key frame (the "inpoint" in the concat demyzer) inpoint to use during the different steps.
